# Batch file - Download the latest FTP folder

Tags: batch-file, ftp

I'm trying to download the latest folder from an FTP server. This folder contains several folders in which contains several CSV files.

The issue I have is that the folders are created each day and each time I run the script I only want it to download the latest folder at that location.

I have not the foggiest idea of how to specify this, or even download an entire folder structure from an FTP using batch file.

Please let me know if any additional information is required and I will provide it immediately, thanks again for your help.

Kind Regards,
Lewis

Comment: How do you tell, what is the "latest folder"? By a name or a timestamp? Or do you have all past folders locally and you want to download all new folders on the server that are not present locally yet?

Comment: Hi Martin, the folders will be timestamped on the server, they wont be saved locally. (Unless this is necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to select the most recent folder with the built-in Windows FTP client, the `ftp.exe`. You would have more luck with a PowerShell script and the [`FtpWebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest).

But even if you manage to select the most recent directory, neither the `ftp.exe` nor the `FtpWebRequest` support recursive downloads anyway.

You better use some more powerful 3rd party FTP client.

---

For example with [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/) you can download the latest file or folder, using the `-latest` switch of the [`get` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get) (WinSCP 5.9 and newer):

```
winscp.com /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "cd /remote/path" ^
    "lcd c:\local\path" ^
    "get -latest *" ^
    "exit"
```

See also the guide to [downloading the most recent file with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Thanks Martin, i appreciate the suggestion, ill give it a try.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl Thanks, however this is not working for me as it downloads the last file, not the latest folder... Do you have a suggestion for the latest **folder**? (besides, my folder is timestamped, would it help?)

Comment: @JejeBelfort Do you mean that you have also files in the source folder, but you want to exclude those from the evaluation of the "latest" entry?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes correct! In the end I found another working solution, I just called a `.vbs` script returning me yesterday's date (i.e. the name of the folder I want to copy) and pass it to the `get` function. Thanks

Comment: @JejeBelfort WinSCP can calculate yesterday date on its own: `get prefix%TIMESTAMP-1D#yyyy-mm-dd%suffix` - See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#timestamp